# RSA with open SSL in lazarus

Tags: cryptography, rsa, pascal, lazarus

I have a question :
How can I generate an 18-digits prime number with OpenSSL in Lazarus ?
even I searched the web , I don`t know the command yet ,
thank you all

Comment: "I really need ..." and "I need a simple answer..." are not sentences that will do you any favors here, we don't work for you. I would recommend removing them. I see OpenSSL headers are available for free Pascal. What is your actual problem: generating the prime of sufficient size or calling the OpenSSL functions? What have you tried?

Comment: Please check my question at the math site, and then especially [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1587285/229184)

Answer (score 1):

So the simplest thing you can do is to look for primes yourself using random numbers generated by OpenSSL:

1. generate pseudo-random integer r within the range 5e17 - 5e16 using the `BN_rand_range` function;
2. add 5e16 to r giving you x
3. calculate y by performing `BN_add(BN_mul(2, x), 1)`;
4. if `BN_is_prime_ex(y)` returns OK for `BN_prime_checks` then you found your prime, otherwise goto 1.

Comment: That's as far as I go, you can do the rest of the programming and linking yourself. Maybe others will go further for you, I don't know.